# Updating one instance of a class causes another to update

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a basic program that simulates shuffling a deck of cards and drawing cards into a hand. After drawing, I give the class variables in the deck array for the card drawn the values of 0 and null, for rank and suit, as a check to see if the card is drawn from the deck. However, when I set the card in the deck array to 0 and null it also sets the card in the hand array to the same. Any suggestions for solutions to the problem are much appreciated. Thanks!

The code for the Draw Card button:

```
Card drawn = new Card(0, null);
        //
        do
        {
            i++;
            drawn = test.cards[i];
        } while (drawn.rank == 0 || drawn.suit == null);
        //
        output = drawn.rank + " " + drawn.suit;
        lblOutput.Text = output;
        //
        addToHand(drawn);
        if (handCount < 5)
        {
            handCount++;
        }
        test.cards[i].suit = null;
        test.cards[i].rank = 0;
        //
        if (i >= 51)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have drawn all the cards.");
            btnDraw.Enabled = false;
            btnShuffle.Enabled = false;
        }
```

The addToHand function:

```
private void addToHand(Card drawn)
    {
        if (handCount < 5)
        {
                if (hand[0].suit == null)
                {
                    hand[0] = drawn;
                    button1.Text = hand[0].rank + " " + hand[0].suit;
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (hand[1].suit == null)
                {
                    hand[1] = drawn;
                    button2.Text = hand[1].rank + " " + hand[1].suit;
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (hand[2].suit == null)
                {
                    hand[2] = drawn;
                    button3.Text = hand[2].rank + " " + hand[2].suit;
                    button3.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (hand[3].suit == null)
                {
                    hand[3] = drawn;
                    button4.Text = hand[3].rank + " " + hand[3].suit;
                    button4.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (hand[4].suit == null)
                {
                    hand[4] = drawn;
                    button5.Text = hand[4].rank + " " + hand[4].suit;
                    button5.Enabled = true;
                }
        }
```

And here are the classes for the deck and cards:

```
public class Deck
{
    public Card[] cards;

    public Deck() //Fills new array with 52 cards
    {
        cards = new Card[52];
        var index = 0;

        foreach (var suit in new[] { "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", })
        {
            for (var rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++)
            {
                cards[index++] = new Card(rank, suit);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Card
{
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public string suit { get; set; }

    public Card(int rk, string st)
    {
        rank = rk;
        suit = st;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's kind of the basics of reference types. Instead of assigning `test.cards[i].suit` to `null`, set the entire card `test.cards[i]` to `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# objects are inherently pass by reference, not pass by value.  So when you do this:

```
Card card = cards[0];
```

You're not creating a new card, you're referencing an already created card.  So when you change the value of cards[0], every reference to that value changes.

You'll likely want to "clone" it, or in your case, just copy all the data within the card.

```
Card card = new Card();
card.suit = cards[0].suit;
card.rank = cards[0].rank;
```

Anything not a value type you will need to clone in the same manner.

Comment: "primitive types, such as int and string, are passed by value", this is wrong. Not primitives, only primitives that are value types. You can also create any `struct` which will behave exactly the same way as `int`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

When you write `hand[0] = drawn;` hand[0] and drawn are the same object.
If you want to have the same value but in two distinct object you can either :

- Use a copy constructor : `new Hand(drawn)`
- Use the `Clone` method of the drawn objet (impement ICloneable).

You could be interrested by the IClonneable interface :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx

And also by copy constructor :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor